# C++ handling many derived classes with static keyword or indexed templates

Tags: c++, templates, module, static

My intention is, whenever I add a new derived class, I need it registered in a list of class names in some other class object so that all newly added classes can be used for a process. But doing this without writing something extra to other classes by hand takes more time.

I have lots of derived classes to maintain such as adding them to a list, checking their names and similar things. Now I'm up to make this automated. What I could think of is

- have each derived class contain a static member initializer which also adds its own name to base class' static list so that program scheduler parses that list and handles preparations.
- look at folder that contains source files(derived class class definitions) with same naming scheme and build a list out of it(again, using names)
- have each derived class own a number that is a template type and iterate it in the base class until it gives error

all these may not be suitable for production or at least may not be working at all times, for example, static keyword doesn't work unless a class is used once, but I can't initialize a class if I don't know of. The second choice is not secure, the third I don't know if it could crash the program when integer index of template goes out of border.

How dangerous is to increment

```
 // try until error, can compiler compile this?
 while(noError)
 {
     tryInit(new MyClass<ctr>()).addToList();
 }
 // or
 tryInit(new MyClass<2>()).addToList();
 tryInit(new MyClass<3>()).addToList();
 tryInit(new MyClass<4>()).addToList();
 tryInit(new MyClass<5>()).addToList();
```

what happens if there are no 5 derived classes?

Is there a beyond static keyword that makes a class load right at the program startup, even without forward declaration or anything else?

Comment: classes are not "modules", and calling them so obfuscates your question.

Comment: ok fixing it im sorry.

Comment: I have no idea after reading your explanation what you are trying to do. But I can answer the direct question. *"what happens if there are no 5 derived classes?"* If no explicit specialization for `MyClass<5>` is defined, and neither is the primary template, you will get a compiler error here. If there is an explicit specialization, it will be used. Otherwise, the compiler will try to instantiate the primary template with `5` as its argument.

Comment: Do you mean if I use just `template <int N>` without any specialization and try with a while loop,  it fails?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "use". Do you plan to only declare the primary template, or both declare and define it? If the former, naturally it cannot be instantiated. If the latter, then the compiler would at least try to instantiate it for any argument; it may or may not succeed.

Comment: Instead of adding a new derived class everytime, adding a derived template specialization for example class A:B<25> { here initializes one element of B's static list (adds something like a name) }. as a 25th feature of program so that program knows there is a new feature by looking at only B, but without using A even once, only at start of program automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is possible, if somewhat unsafe/obnoxious

```
template<int>
struct MyClass : std::false_type {};

template<>
struct MyClass<0> : std::true_type
{
    static void foo(int i) { std::cout << i << " is useful!" << std::endl; }
};

// and so on...
```

To add a new class, just add another specialization of `MyClass`.

To iterate over all of them

```
template<int n>
void foo_all_(int i)
{
    if constexpr(MyClass<n>::value)
    {
        MyClass<n>::foo(i);
        foo_all_<n + 1>(i);
    }
}

void foo_all(int i)
{
    foo_all_<0>(i);
}
```

The unsafe/obnoxious part is that all `MyClass` has to be properly specialized and defined for this to work.

I would imagine having such a family of classes is useful only with polymorphism, which could make this a bit friendlier

```
struct Base : std::true_type { /* ... */ };

template<int>
struct MyClass {};    

template<>
struct MyClass<0> : Base { /* ... */ };
```

And hold instances of `MyClass` with `Base` references.

Comment: Is there a way to force this scheme for any new class declarations to ensure no error happens later? (such as declaring pure virtual to force implementation of it)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes, just use pure virtual as you said in `Base`